# How to use multiple storage states in different devices (browsers)

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

So I have spent my day banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out.  What I have is a set of tests, a subset of which have to be run in 2 browsers, but the rest only need to be run in one(chromium).

I've got them defined in playwright.config.ts this way:

```
 projects: [

{
  name: 'setup',
  testDir: './',
  testMatch: /.*\.setup\.js/
},

{
  name: 'Desktop Chrome',
  use: {
    browserName: 'chromium',
    storageState: '.auth/specialuser1.json'
  },
  dependencies: ['setup']
},

{
  name: 'Desktop Firefox',
  use: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    storageState: '.auth/specialuser2.json'
  },
  dependencies: ['setup']
},
```

The problem I have is that while this works just fine for the subset of tests, when I need to run the rest of the tests in chromium, I can't use that storagestate 'specialuser1.json'.   I need to do a normal login process using other sets of credentials in the beforeAll for those tests.

How can I define/configure this so that it ONLY uses the storage state if I'm running the special subset of tests?

Note that I've already went down the path of creating a duplicate of the Desktop Chrome section, like so:

```
    {
  name: 'Special Chrome',
  testDir: '/specialtests'
  use: {
    browserName: 'chromium',
    storageState: '.auth/contractsuser1.json'
  },
  dependencies: ['setup']
},
```

And adding a corresponding line in the 'Desktop Chrome' section to ignore the special tests and removing the storage state line:

```
   {
  name: 'Special Chrome',
  testIgnore: '/specialtests'
  use: {
    browserName: 'chromium',
  },
  dependencies: ['setup']
},
```

But when I kick off the job to run the special tests, because of that ignore line, it tells me there are no tests found.

Dan

Comment: This is tagged playwright-java. Was that intended? .ts file looks like a TypeScript project.

Comment: Hello, did you check https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures#fixtures-options
You can create test fixture and pass it from project.
Meaning from project you can declare specific variable or logic that fixture will handle and execute your tests from project based on that.

Comment: Did you solve this yet? Happy to take a look if not